# How could I get the sub sum of a value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following [relation.]
[image: 1]

With some of the following data:

```
dates
+---------+------------+------+-------+------+
| dateKey | date       | day  | month | year |
+---------+------------+------+-------+------+
|       1 | 01/01/2020 |    1 |     1 | 2000 |
|       2 | 02/01/2020 |    2 |     1 | 2000 |
|     ... |        ... |  ... |   ... |  ... |
+---------+------------+------+-------+------+

sales
+------------+------------+----------+------+
| dateKey    | companyKey | produced | sold |
+------------+------------+----------+------+
|          1 | 1          |        0 |    0 |
|          1 | 2          |        0 |    0 |
|          1 | 3          |       12 |    2 |
|          1 | 4          |      123 |   12 |
|     ...    | ...        |      ... |  ... |
|        365 | 12         |     1234 |  123 |
+------------+------------+----------+------+

company
|------------+----------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| companyKey | companyAcronym |        companyName      | employeeNumber |
+------------+----------------+-------------------------+----------------+
|          1 |         AAL    | Anit and Alson Limited  |            251 |
|          2 |         ABB    | Abban                   |             26 |
|          3 |         AND    | Andelson                |             57 |
|          4 |         APL    | Aperal                  |            137 |
|          5 |         BAN    | Bansil                  |             72 |
|        ... |         ...    | ...                     |            ... |
|------------+----------------+-------------------------+----------------+
```

I am trying to get the total number of goods sold per month by each company. What I have tried so far is this:

```
SELECT month, companyName, SUM(sales) AS totalSales
FROM sales AS s 
JOIN company AS c ON s.companyKey = c.companyKey
JOIN dates AS d ON s.dateKey = d.dateKey
GROUP BY companyName , month;
```

This doesn't work, as I still get a row for each day of the month.

Comment: `dateKey` in dates is an integer and in sales it's a varchar (or a date?). Why do you join on these unrelated columns?

Comment: You can't really edit the question to have the same code as the answer that was provided without at least leaving a comment on the answer that gave you the code.  There is no way for the author of the answer to know you edited your code to match their's so they don't know their answer didn't help.

Comment: Edited the question fixing issues pointed out by @forpas and eshirvana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to group by companyname and month:

```
SELECT month, year , companyName, SUM(sold) AS totalSales
FROM sales2 AS s 
JOIN company AS c ON s.companyKey = c.companyKey
JOIN dates AS d ON s.dateKey = d.dateKey
GROUP BY companyname , month, year
```

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to add that in the question, sorry.